# When releasing standalone messages extension on app store do I need iOS app screenshots?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, ios10, ios-messages-extension

I am releasing a standalone iOS messages extension on the app store meaning there is not an iOS app to go along with it. Do I have to include screenshots for the iOS app or can I just add the screenshots for the messages extension?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Comment: This is a valid question and I got a valid answer. Why do you feel the need to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an iOS app, how would you add screenshots for an iOS app?

**Besides:**

> For all iMessage apps **and** iOS extensions, provide separate sets of screenshots of your iMessage content for iPhone 6 Plus and iPad Pro. These screenshots will be used across device sizes. You can upload up to five screenshots per set to showcase the iMessage experience. You will need to upload your screenshots to both the App Preview and Screenshots section and the iMessage section of your app’s version page in My Apps on iTunes Connect.
>   When showing conversations in Messages, make sure the information and accounts you display are not real. Do not display phone numbers. For screenshot specifications, see the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/imessage-app-submissions/

Comment: Thanks haven't seen that page before big help :)

Comment: There are sections "iOS App" AND "iMessage App" where you can upload screenshots, even if you have a standalone extension. The question was: Should you? I don't understand this answer.

Comment: You have to upload screenshots for both sections (don't ask why). Just use the same set of screenshots. iTunes Connect is seldom logical ;-)